# Knit Japanese Characters in R

Tags: r, pdf, character

I have the following code :

```
title("1月 / January", line = -1, adj=0)
main("チェックインロビー ")
```

However when I knit to pdf it just makes the japanese characters question marks.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: can you share the output of `Sys.getlocale()`

Comment: I am quite new to R, I do not have getlocale specified. How do I do this?

Comment: What do you get if you simply run `Sys.getlocale()` from the R console?

Comment: Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_CTYPE=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_MONETARY=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Japanese_Japan.932"